# Text Area Height in 3-column Layout Text Cannot Be Set in Percentage

Tags: css, html, layout

I am attempting to create a 3-column layout using two text areas. I can set the text area width so that the columns look correctly, but the height is shrunken. I am looking for a solution that will work with HTML5-compatible browsers - older ones do not need to be supported. See jsfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ExPraliteMonk/NhSpb/)

### HTML5

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="content">
        <div id="columnLeft">
            <div id="toc">This is a table of contents</div>
        </div>
        <div id="columnCenter">
            <textarea>This is edit 1.</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="columnRight">
            <textarea>This is edit 2.</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
height: 100%;
}
#content {
height: 100%;
}
#columnLeft, #columnCenter, #columnRight {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
margin-right: 5px;
}
#columnLeft {
width: 10%;
float: left;
}
#columnCenter {
width: 40%;
float: left;
}
#columnRight {
width: 40%;
float: right;
}
textarea {
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
resize: none;
}
```

How can I set the text area height in 3-column layout text to percentage, or with a layout format that makes the text area height look proportionate?

Comment: Don't wrap your HTML content with `<html>` and `<body>` when making a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) -- it automatically does that afterwards. Your page currently has multiple `<html>` and `<body>` tags ([view the source of this](http://jsfiddle.net/ExPraliteMonk/NhSpb/show/)) which is of course a mess.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Removed the html and body tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to define the `wrap`'s height.

```
#wrap {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/NhSpb/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Other poster is correct. You forgot a `height: 100%` on div#wrap.

Here is a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/ksokhan/NhSpb/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height dynamically in Javascript

```
$("textarea").height($("#columnLeft").height());​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UMxVU/)